# how can i make a background process in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a real-time internet connection check. how can i make a background process in jetpack compose? What would be the best way to do this? I am using the following code:

```
   val connectionType = mutableStateOf("")

    suspend fun run(context:Context) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Invoking the Connectivity Manager
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        while (true) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
                val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw)
                if (actNw != null) {
                    when {
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> connectionType.value =
                            "Conexão WIFI"
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> connectionType.value =
                            "Conexão Dados Celular"
                        //for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> connectionType.value =
                            "Conexão Ethernet"
                        //for check internet over Bluetooth
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> connectionType.value =
                            "Conexão Bluetooth"
                        else -> connectionType.value = "Sem conexão"

                    }
                } else {
                    connectionType.value = "Sem conexão"
                }
            } else {
                val netInfo = connectivityManager.allNetworkInfo

                for (ni in netInfo) {
                    if (ni.typeName.equals("WIFI", ignoreCase = true))
                        if (ni.isConnected) connectionType.value = "Conexão WIFI"
                    if (ni.typeName.equals("MOBILE", ignoreCase = true))
                        if (ni.isConnected) connectionType.value =
                            "Conexão de Dados Celular"
                        else {
                            connectionType.value = "Sem conexão"
                        }
                }
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ConnectionChecker() {
        val context = LocalContext.current

        connectionType.value = remember {
            connectionType.value
        }

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            run(context)
        }

    }
```

It works perfectly but in terms of performance is there a better way?

Comment: https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/core/data/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/core/data/util/ConnectivityManagerNetworkMonitor.kt from the now in android source. its similar to the  answer posted here with little change.

Answer (score 3):

**Let me tell you a better way to check internet connection in jetpack compose**

First make `NetworkUtility.kt` file and paste the below code there. This will return the connection state (Available , UnAvailable).

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.State
import androidx.compose.runtime.produceState
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow

val Context.currentConnectivityState: ConnectionState
    get() {
        val connectivityManager =
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        return getCurrentConnectivityState(connectivityManager)
    }

private fun getCurrentConnectivityState(
    connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
): ConnectionState {
    val connected = connectivityManager.allNetworks.any { network ->
        connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
            ?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            ?: false
    }

    return if (connected) ConnectionState.Available else ConnectionState.Unavailable
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun Context.observeConnectivityAsFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val callback = NetworkCallback { connectionState -> trySend(connectionState) }

    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .build()

    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, callback)

    // Set current state
    val currentState = getCurrentConnectivityState(connectivityManager)
    trySend(currentState)

    // Remove callback when not used
    awaitClose {
        // Remove listeners
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback)
    }
}

fun NetworkCallback(callback: (ConnectionState) -> Unit): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    return object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            callback(ConnectionState.Available)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            callback(ConnectionState.Unavailable)
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun connectivityState(): State<ConnectionState> {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Creates a State<ConnectionState> with current connectivity state as initial value
    return produceState(initialValue = context.currentConnectivityState) {
        // In a coroutine, can make suspend calls
        context.observeConnectivityAsFlow().collect { value = it }
    }
}

sealed class ConnectionState {
    object Available : ConnectionState()
    object Unavailable : ConnectionState()
}
```

Now you have to handle above state in your composable function . Go to your composable function and write the below code there .

```
 val connection by connectivityState()
 val isConnected = connection == ConnectionState.Available
```

The isConnected variable stores true or false (true means connected with internet and false means not connected)

```
if (!isConnected) InternetConnection()
```

if it's not connected with internet just show below msg.

```
@Composable
fun InternetConnection(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(redColor), contentAlignment = Center
    ) {
        Text15_500(
            text = stringResource(R.string.internet_connection),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp, start = 10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpful

Answer (score 1):

This code looks fine only some refactor I can suggest.
`connectionType` can be declared as this
`var connectionType by remember { mutableStateOf("") }`

and your `run` method can be renamed as `checkInternetConnection` method and place it out of this `Activity` or `Fragment`. You can keep it inside some utility, so it provide more re-usability. Please dont pass the context to that, you can create the `connectivityManager` inside the `LaunchedEffect` and pass it that function, and get the result as lambda so it looks more readable too.

After refactor your `ConnectionChecker`  will look like this.

```
@Composable
fun ConnectionChecker() {
    var connectionType by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        checkInternetConnection(connectivityManager) {
            connectionType = it
        }
    }
    Text(text = "Hello $connectionType!")
}
```

and your `checkInternetConnection` will look like...

```
suspend fun checkInternetConnection(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager, updateConnectionType: (String) -> Unit) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Invoking the Connectivity Manager
        while (true) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
                val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw)
                if (actNw != null) {
                    when {
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ->
                            updateConnectionType("Conexão WIFI")

                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ->
                            updateConnectionType("Conexão Dados Celular")

                        // for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) ->
                            updateConnectionType("Conexão Ethernet")
                        // for check internet over Bluetooth
                        actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) ->
                            updateConnectionType("Conexão Bluetooth")

                        else -> updateConnectionType("Sem conexão")
                    }
                } else {
                    updateConnectionType("Sem conexão")
                }
            } else {
                val netInfo = connectivityManager.allNetworkInfo

                for (ni in netInfo) {
                    if (ni.typeName.equals("WIFI", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        if (ni.isConnected) updateConnectionType("Conexão WIFI")
                    }
                    if (ni.typeName.equals("MOBILE", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        if (ni.isConnected) updateConnectionType("Conexão de Dados Celular")
                        else {
                            updateConnectionType("Sem conexão")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
```